# error installing scrapy on python 3.6.2

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to install scrapy for my project. But after following installation instructions, I got the following error:

> scrapy is not recognized as internal command

Please help me out!

Comment: how did you install scrapy? You even didn't mention which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 64 bit.. I installed scrapy using pip install command

Comment: Try using `easy_install scrapy`

Comment: I tried the above command .. Scrapy requires Twisted Framework 13.1.0 ..